# How to make a cpp (Rcpp) function that triggers "useful" error messages if the input types are wrong?

Tags: c++, r, error-handling, rcpp

Consider this cpp function

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int timesTwo(int x) {
  return x * 2;
}
```

If I input an object of wrong type in this function (e.g. "character"), apparently, it will not work and show this error message
`Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer].`

However, I want to make it a bit more informative, for example

```
Error in timesTwo(int x)
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer].
```

or

```
Error in the parameter x of timesTwo(int x)
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=integer].
```

I want to know how I can do it in cpp?

Comment: https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/intro-to-exceptions/ gives some ideas (though not perfect)

Comment: Why not write an R wrapper function that does the type checking, emits helpful errors, and only dispatches the cpp function if conditions are met? Alternatively, write the cpp function to accept any SEXP instead of an int, and do the type checking inside it.

Comment: That error message seems to have been [generated by rcpp itself](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/79211e78be8bb5bb7fc21c90c7222ef4a8c566b4/inst/include/Rcpp/r_cast.h#L59-L70) You could try improving this in Rcpp yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two obvious ways to handle this. The first is that you invoke your cpp function via a wrapper in R that does your type checking in advance. For example:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  int times_two_cpp(int x) {
    return x * 2;
  }')

timesTwo <- function(x) {
  if(!is.integer(x)) stop("'x' should be an integer, not ", typeof(x))
  times_two_cpp(x)
}
```

Testing, we have:

```r
timesTwo(5L)
#> [1] 10

timesTwo('hello')
#> Error in timesTwo("hello") : 'x' should be an integer, not character
```

The second option is to allow your C++ function to take any R object, and do the type-checking internally. This requires some knowledge of R internals

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction('
  Rcpp::IntegerVector timestwo(SEXP x) {
    if(TYPEOF(x) != INTSXP) {
     Rcpp::stop("in the parameter x of timesTwo - x is not an integer");
    }
    Rcpp::IntegerVector result(x);
    return result * 2;
   }
')
```

Resulting in

```r
timestwo(5L)
#> [1] 10

timestwo('hello')
#> Error: in the parameter x of timesTwo - x is not an integer
```